# Repeat last statement in the Q shell

Tags: kdb, q-lang

The Q programming language has an associated shell. How does one access his last input in the shell? For example, if I type:

```
q) a:45
```

in the next prompt `q)`, I would like to recover `a:45` by hitting the up arrow (as in bash), however, this does not work in the Q console. What does work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Linux or OS X you should use [rlwrap](http://code.kx.com/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_recall_and_edit_keyboard_input.3F). It is included in most Linux package repositories. On OS X I installed rlwrap via [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/), which requires Xcode to be installed.

On Windows the q console comes with this functionality and you don't need to install anything.